# build dynamic breadcrumbs in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, breadcrumbs

Here i want to create breadcrumbs based on my database.Here is my database please have a look

```
resource_category_id    category_name   parent_category     
    1                            Tools                  0    
    2                    product literature             0   
    3                   Terms and Conitions             0   
    4                        crane library              1   
    5                         geniune                   1   
    6                       lift planning               1   
    8                         cranimax                  6
```

My controller looks like this

```
$data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->Manito_model->get_breadcrumbs_details($resource_id);
```

Here is my model

```
 public function get_breadcrumbs_details($resource_id)
{
 $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM resource_category as c1 WHERE c1.resource_category_id = $resource_id UNION SELECT * FROM resource_category as c2 where c2.resource_category_id = 6 ");
    return $query->result();


}
```

Here is my view please have a look

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home">Home Page</a></li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Resource</a></li>

<?php $breadcrumb = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
 if($breadcrumb){
   foreach($breadcrumb as $bread){

    ?>
<li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><?php echo $bread->category_name;?></li>
<?php }}?>
```

Here my `$resource_id=8`,so i assume my result to be like this  `tools/lift planning/cranimax.`

Now am getting the result like this `lift planning/cranimax`.but how can we get breadcrumbs if it contains multiple multiple childs

Comment: anybody have any idea

Comment: Please post your error message.